# Is Fiddler a Good Building Block for an Internet Filter?

Tags: fiddler

So I want to make my own Internet Filter. Don't worry, i'm not asking for a tutorial. I'm just wondering if Fiddler would make a good backbone for it. I'm a little worried because it seemed that there's a few things Fiddler can't always pick up - or that there are workarounds. So, my question:

1. Would Fiddler grab all web data? i.e, chats, emails, websites, etc.
2. Are there any known workarounds?
3. Any other reasons not to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) rather than Fiddler. Fiddler(Core) is a web proxy meaning it captures HTTP/HTTPS traffic; it won't capture traffic that uses other protocols (e.g. IRC, etc). To capture traffic from other protocols, you'll need a lower-level interception point (e.g. a Windows Firewall filter) which will capture everything, but it will not be able to decrypt HTTPS traffic, and parsing / modifying the traffic will prove MUCH harder.

Comment: yes, FiddlerCore. thanks. Do you see any potential disadvantages in using this for a filter? could a power user work around it?

Comment: Anyone (with admin permissions) can work around anything on their box.